# lower integral when integral is infinity

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I have $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ a measurable space, and $f:X \rightarrow [-\infty,+\infty]$ a measurable function with, $\int_{X} f^{-} < + \infty$ and $\int_{X} f^{+}=+\infty$. My question is pretty simple, since $\int_{X}f^{+}=+\infty$, is the lower integral of $f^{+}$ also $+\infty$ or it can be strictly less than $+\infty$?

Comment: If f is to be "integrable" then the "upper" and "lower" integrals must be the same.  They certainly can be different but in that case, f is not integrable.

Comment: I know, and of course f is not "integrable", I just need to know how is the "lower" integral of a function if its integral is infinity. In this case I'm wondering how is the "lower" integral of f+ because I'm pretty sure that its "upper" integral is infinity.

Comment: Could one phrase your question as follows?: "Is there a nonnegative function whose lower integral is a finite number while its upper integral is $\infty$?"

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the Dirichlet function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ given by 
$$
f(x)=
 \begin{cases}
  1, & \text{if}\ x\in \mathbb R\!\smallsetminus\!\mathbb Q \\
  0, & \text{otherwise.}
 \end{cases}
$$
Then the Lebesgue integral of $f$ is $\lambda(\mathbb R\!\smallsetminus\!\mathbb Q)=+\infty$ but the (Darboux or Riemann) lower integral of $f$ is zero because no matter how fine you choose a partition, each partition-interval will include rational numbers.